# How to get AccessToken in Office365

Tags: outlook, access-token, office365api

I'm trying to use Office365(outlook) API to read emails.
sending a GET request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages with the accesstoken in Request Header will get me the inbox.
Access token expires after some time and i want to get the access token dynamically now.
Can you please suggest and help me a way to get the accesstoken dynamically?

Comment: How do you retrieve the token in the first place? You can get a refresh token, which you can then use to get a new access token.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko do you know any way which i can read emails via outlook API?

Comment: Which Outlook API? Outlook Object Model under Windows and desktop version of Outlook?